# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab fails as a synchronous callback after chrome.tabs.update?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, callback

I am currently trying to figure out how to automate screen capture on a Chrome browser via an extension. I've arrived at `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` but is running into a curious issue:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true }, function() {
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(data) {
            // Going to canvas that data so hard...
            // The system's going think it's tainted
          });
    });
```

The above fails with the message:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.captureVisibleTab: Failed to capture tab: unknown error
    at Object.capture [as callback]
```

**BUT**, if I change it to the following:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true }, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(data) {
                // Going to canvas that data so hard...
                // The system's going think it's tainted
              });
        }, 0);
    });
```

The code goes through with no issues. However, the callback is ultimately asynchronous. My extension at the moment can automate multiple tabs in "parallel". I worry that there might be a chance more than one `chrome.tabs.update` is called before the first `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` is executed.

Thoughts? Something I overlooked? Or a potentially a bug? Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Like when would you call `chrome.tabs.update` and your `manifest.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `"permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>" ]` in manifest.json.  That fixed it for me.